# Converting pre to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, pre

How would you proceed to transform this :

```
<pre>
key 1 value 1

key 2 value 2
value 2.2


key 3 value 3
value 3.1
value 3.2
value 3.3

key 4 value4.1 value4.5

</pre>
```

To this :

```
<div><pre>
key 1 value 1
</pre></div><div><pre>
key 2 value 2
value 2.2
</pre></div><div><pre>
key 3 value 3
value 3.1
value 3.2
value 3.3
</pre></div><div><pre>
key 4 value4.1 value4.5

</pre></div>
```

Namely : remplacing **continuous** blank line***s*** (could contains space/tabs and multiples linefeed) to `</pre></div><div><pre>`

I tried :

```
var txt = $('pre').text();
txt = txt.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "</pre></div><div><pre>");
$('div#test').append(txt);
```

Partially work : each line are changed, I loose my blocks.

Are `<pre>` line break stocked as \r ? \n ? (all OS? all browsers?)
What would be a good regex to do this?
Any other way you would suggest me to proceed with?

Comment: Your HTML you want to convert to is invalid. <div><pre>key 1 value 1</div></pre> isn't correct.

Comment: Fixed. 2 ups? Some people are purist much :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does it for me. It could be better:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var lines = $('pre').html().split(/\n\s*\n/);
$('pre').remove();
    for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        if($.trim(lines[i].length) > 0){
            var preDiv = $('<pre />');
            var keyDiv = $('<div />');
            preDiv.append(keyDiv);
            keyDiv.html(lines[i]);
            $('body').append(preDiv);
        }
    }

});
```

It doesnt address any whitespace. You can remove it with trim() in the line `keyDiv.html("key" + $.trim(lines[i]))`

Comment: the "key 1 value 1" was just sample data. It could have been anything (not consistant).

Comment: It does not work unless the blank lines are empty (no white spaces), see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J67r2/2/). Best answer so far however.

Answer (score 1):

1. parse the text so you get a list of lines of text
2. trim each line
3. wrap each line in `<div><pre>` tags
4. concatenate the results together

I would do a remove of the prexisting pre element altogether after parsing out the text. So instead of "transforming" it just extract the text and build a different element altogether.

Comment: @Kraz: no my algorithm is different from the one you tried. You were actually replacing spaces with HTML tags, whereas mine would result in a much cleaner implementation. I don't have time to implement it for you right now sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function

```
$('pre').text($.trim($(this).text()).wrap('<div></div>');
```

Comment: That does not achieve what he is trying to do.

Comment: That won't do what he wants. He is wanting to wrap each part with a `<div />` not just the entire thing.

Comment: This will wrap each `<pre>` with a div? what else are you trying to do?